# VBA Copy Pivot Table

Tags: vba, pivot-table

Hi i want to copy my pivot table to another sheet. However there is an error with object doesn't support this property or method

```
Sub Project1()
Dim Table1 As PivotTable

Set Table1 = Worksheets("Bklg Pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable2")
Table1.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table2").Range("A1")


End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

The `PivotTable` object does not have a `Copy` method which is why your attempt is failing. Available methods are listed in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pivottable-object-excel).

You can use the [`TableRange2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.pivottable.tablerange2.aspx) property of the source `PivotTable` to copy as this returns a `Range` object which does have a `Copy` method. Below is an example where I am copying a `PivotTable` to another range within the same sheet.

> TableRange2: Returns a Range object that represents the range
>   containing the entire PivotTable report, including page fields.
>   Read-only.

```
Sub CopyPivot()

    Dim pvt As PivotTable

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Set pvt = .PivotTables("PivotTable1")

        pvt.TableRange2.Copy .Range("E1") 'copy to another area within same sheet

   End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks I used this. Nice and clean and simple.